# Remove Shipping Method

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipping

What is the right way to remove the shipping method in the checkout page? I have tried to follow some tutorials, but most of them don't seemed to work in 1.7 version.

Comment: For Magento 1.9 targeted solutions see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout

Answer (score 4):

Most suggestions on this page are outdated by this time or don't work. I just tested [MageTitan's Skip Shipping extension](http://www.mojo-code.com/item/magetitans-skip-shipping-method/) on Magento 1.7.0.2 and it works fine. The shipping method step is removed and the cheapest shipping method is automatically selected.

Comment: I tried the module, and can recommend it. One block override, `OnepageController` override but still works fine.

Comment: i.amniels  & @Tim the link is not working, can you post the code here.

Answer (score 2):

please follow this link

[Method-1](http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.in/2012/04/magento-onestep-checkout-remove.html)

or

[Method-2](http://knowledgevalley.blogspot.in/2012/01/magento-skip-shipping-method-from.html)

it may help you

Comment: I have tried those tutorials.Both of them do not work in 1.7 version.For example,`Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage` does not have `$stepCodes` variable.

Comment: I followed the 2nd tutorial and it worked, but if I remember, I needed to make a change. The sample code wasn't 100%

Answer (score 1):

Override following methods:

In `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage.php`:

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping'/*, 'shipping_method'*/, 'payment', 'review');
}
```

and in `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`:

```
public function saveShippingAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin Kolev and welcome to MageOverflow. Thanks for the answer. But recommending core hacks is a bad idea. You should at least recommend to copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage`.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to remove a Shipping method is to disable it in the Magento Backend.  Go to the `System -> Configuration` section of the Magento admin, and click the `Shipping Information` link under the Sales table.  Each shipping method listed should have an `Enabled` option.

Set this to "No", and the shipping method should be disabled.

[image]

Comment: If all shipping methods are disabled, how can we proceed to next step after shipping method in the checkout process

Comment: @blakcaps Ah, it wasn't clear from your question you wanted to disable the shipping step entirely.  That, to my knowledge, isn't a feature of Magento out of the box. Most shops I've see that want that behavior set a flat rate shipping that's free, and have it be the only option.

Comment: Idea is to hide the shipping method in the frontend and   set free shipping as the default shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around which may be a good option for some people. If the other options are not your thing, you can add an id or class to the shipping method in your theme's /template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml page.

Add something like:

```
id="shipping_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"
```

To the shipping method in available.phtml

Should look something like:

```
<input id="shipping_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"  name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>
```

Then in CSS you can display:none it:

```
#shipping_method_flat_rate { display:none;}
```

note: technically the option is still on the page so it would be possible to open chrome and inspect element, un- display:none it and submit the form with that option selected.

Comment: Would this even work??