# remove Shipping method under checkout in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

I wanted to remove Shipping method under checkout in magento.

I used this extension "Magetitan skippshipping method" using " Direct package file upload."

But it did't works. after that i copied every files into respective folder.

but still it's not working.

Can anyone give me the "Paste key extension" to remove or skip "shipping method."

I used zip format in windows . but i can't able to install magento extensions using Direct package file upload.

How to install magento extension properly using " Direct package file upload."

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily remove shipping step from onepage checkout in magento, please go through with this post: [How to remove steps from the Magento Onepage checkout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-to-remove-steps-from-the-magento-onepage-checkout/7187#7187)

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow this link
http://knowledgevalley.blogspot.in/2012/01/magento-skip-shipping-method-from.html

Or

[Remove Shipping Method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/remove-shipping-method)