# Magento One Page Checkout Issue on SSL

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I followed the instructions on the following page ("[Remove Shipping steps in Onepage Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout/69669#69669)") to enable the skipping of the shipping method on the one page checkout system of Magento 1.9 CE. It works absolutely perfectly on my local non SSL dev site however when moved to our staging SSL enabled site the functionality seems to be ignored.

I can see from the console log that on local the `saveBilling` function returns `{"goto_section":"payment","update_section":{"name":"payment-method"` as the next step where on the SSL enabled site `shippingMethod` is returned as the next step.

Any help would be fantastic on this!

Comment: Looking into it more it appears any custom module seems to stop working on ssl, my custom case studies module also dies on ssl version of the site.