# How to hide a magento shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9

I followed [This tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout) for Hiding shipping method. I am using webkul shipping but it wont work for this? How i fix it

Comment: Hi please raise a ticket at http://webkul.com/ticket and we will look in to the issues thanks

Comment: they said support period completed

Comment: Hi you can extend the support for the issue which you are getting http://store.webkul.com/support.html