# Checkout in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

How to delete Billing Address, Shipping method at Checkout and how to delete Estimate Charges & Taxes  in cart section in magento 1.9 ?

Answer (score 1):

follow this url for remove shipping method:  [Remove Shipping steps in Onepage Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout)

Comment: If this is a duplicate question, it's better to flag the question as such.

Comment: ok benmarks.....