# How to hide shipping method in Magento?

Tags: php, onepage-checkout, magento-1.9.2

I want to hide shipping or don't want to show shipping method in one page checkout page please tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods (Left Side)
```

Click on on shipping method you want to disable and change  Enabled from **Yes** to **No**

If you want to remove shipping method step follow below tutorial.

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-remove-shipping-method-step-one-page-checkout-magento

Or you can check this nice post from Marius

[Remove Shipping steps in Onepage Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout)

Comment: thanks but i want to know how to hide shipping steps form checkout page.

Comment: edited my answer