# Is it possible to hide the shipping method step on magento checkout process

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout, cart, shipping-methods

Is it possible to hide the shipping method step on the Magento checkout process? I want to remove the shipping method step only on the checkout page, not permanently.

What I am trying to achieve is on the cart page when the customer enters his postcode for shipping estimate and then update total. I will want to use the choice he made here for his order. So I see no relevance for him to alter his shipping choice afterward as I only have one shipping option.

I have searched around and found there are ways of removing the step altogether and enabling a default shipping method. However, I am using a table matrix so the shipping charge differs based on postcode entered, so I cannot set it as a default.

Please, can you advise if it is possible to achieve what I want and if so how would I approach it?

Advice and guidance are appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I have seen on methods/explanation on how to remove the shipping step. However, I do not want to remove it altogether. I just want to hide it, but carry on the process. I have tried to remove the step from the Abstract.php file. However, this removes the step, but will not let you proceed to next step

Comment: See this awesome answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53358/231

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I have looked at them and also tried to do them. I have updated my post above. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: I *think* you're conflating "remove the step" with "remove the functionality"  - as long as there is a post code, the method should "work" (guessing, but I'm sure I'm close if not correct).