# magento skip shipping but not remove from checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, onepage-checkout

i have magento store with free shipping , so it is of no use to show shipping step in checkout page.

But i want to manage shipping from admin like fedex tracking and all from admin so that user can track his / her order.

i check few links online they seems to disable and then remove shipping , can i get idea how to do this

Comment: did you checked this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout

Comment: i tried sylvain-rayé solution that does not work i think

Comment: hi , Did you tried  for answer gave by Marius  ?

Comment: it is something different

Comment: did you checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381970/magento-skip-shipping-method-on-checkout-page

Comment: they did magento core modifications so useless , can you give me hint for this or way to do this