# Fatal error: Class 'StackExchange_Checkout_Helper_Data'

Tags: magento-1.9, module, fatal-error

I followed @Marius answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout)

it worked fine in one site, in another site below error once i go to

`System > configuration > Sales > checkout` ,

```
Fatal error: Class 'StackExchange_Checkout_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

**compilation**

```
Compiler Status : Enabled
Compilation State : Compiled
```

**config.xml** - app/code/local/StackExchange/Checkout/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </StackExchange_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage>StackExchange_Checkout_Block_Onepage</onepage><!-- rewrite the onepage chackout block -->
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_checkout>
                <class>StackExchange_Checkout_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_checkout>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <stackexchange_checkout>
                <class>StackExchange_Checkout_Model</class>
            </stackexchange_checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <checkout>
            <options>
                <hide_shipping>1</hide_shipping>
                <default_shipping>tablerate_bestway</default_shipping><!-- set the default shipping method code -->
            </options>
        </checkout>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <StackExchange_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">StackExchange_Checkout</StackExchange_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <StackExchange_Checkout>
                    <files>
                        <default>StackExchange_Checkout.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </StackExchange_Checkout>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: post your `config.xml` too

Comment: do you have compilation on or off?

Comment: @QaisarSatti updated the question.

Comment: @Marius updated the question.

Comment: Disable the compilation and try again

Comment: @Marius Please post your comment as answer. your level of debugging is taller than sky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have the compiler on, you need to disable it each time you add a new extension. You can enable it after that again.

Comment: i am an idiot, did't followed standard procedure to install. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure `app/code/local/StackExchange/Checkout/Helper/Data.php` exists in the right location.

And ensure the class name is correct `StackExchange_Checkout_Helper_Data`

Both file location and class name must be case sensitive

Comment: Thanks, cross checked it, file in right path & class name is also correct.

Comment: Does your configure XML define stackexchange as a helper alias?

Comment: @RobbieAverill can you guide me path of configure XML file

Comment: Config.xml in your modules etc folder

Comment: @RobbieAverill i copy pasted code from that link. please check updated question

Comment: @user9999 please recompile

Comment: Stackexchange_checkout is your helper alias, you have code somewhere that is referencing it as stackexchange. Change your config XML so the helper alias is stackexchange.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism sorry for delay, it worked fine after i recompiled.

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thanks for your support. it worked fine after i recompiled