# Shipping carrier list

Tags: shipping

i'm a newbie.... When i go in backend to orders, i like to ship it and add a tracking number, so in the list there are carriers i don't need. just hide them
how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: means you dont want `shipping method` step ?

Comment: did you founds solution ?

Comment: in which file i can hide DHL, Fedex...

Comment: means you dont want any shipping method step to display under checkout, you want only one shipping method as default ?

Comment: when i add tracking number, i would like to have just my default carrier. no dropdown menu. where can i deactivate them

Comment: its better if you edit question with required details....

Comment: just this thing:  only one shipping method as default, the other carrier remove from this list

Comment: are you looking for this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout

Comment: i'm a newbie.... i dont think it's that.  When i go in backend to orders, i like to ship it and add a tracking nummer, so in the list there are carriers i don't need. just hide them

Comment: okay, please edit question with requirements, so again this question will notified by community..... otherwise no one will check question again....

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Each carrier model must implement the interface `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`.
This interface contains 2 methods.

One of them is called `isTrackingAvailable` and if this returns true, the carrier will appear in the list of carriers.

All you have to do is rewrite the carrier models you don't need (like `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex` for example) and make the method `isTrackingAvailable` return false.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm right in this path?  /app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/fedex.php. i can't finde istrackingavailable.... sorry :-)

Comment: The method is in the parent class.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Can you help me please step by step what i have to do. you have already wroten it, but i don't understand it

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to rewrite a model http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/.  You need to rewrite the model `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex` and add in your new class the method `isTrackingAvailable` that just returns false.