# How to skip shipping method magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any way to skip Shipping method in checkout? i have one checkbox in checkout billing block see below image

[image]

so when customer click on that checkbox then shipping method will be skip.

Comment: working code,check link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53358

Comment: I already check it if i apply then hide shipping method for all customer.

Comment: @hardik so do you want to skip shipping method for some customers, please edit the question with the same......